# java spring websocket send reply from other application

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I have two different java spring applications. First one sends a message using websocket and it works fine.

client:

```
var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/myapp/hello');
            stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
            stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
                console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
                stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greeting', function(greeting){
                    console.log(greeting.body);
                    //showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
                });
            });
```

Server:

```
@MessageMapping("/send/{widgetId}")
    public Greeting userMessage(@DestinationVariable String widgetId,
            UserMessageWrapper userMessageWrapper) throws Exception {
        dispatchMessage(widgetId, userMessageWrapper.getUserToken(),
                userMessageWrapper.getMessage(), userMessageWrapper.getUserAgent());
        return new Greeting("asdasdsa");
    }
```

It works fine, but I need to send a reply to this message from other java application on other server. I have a quartz job there and it scans db and sends replies to subscribed clients using websockets. I want every client to receive only message for him, no broadcasting.

```
public void callJSWebSocket(){
    SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor
            .create(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE);
    headerAccessor.setSubscriptionId("sub-0");
    headerAccessor.setLeaveMutable(true);

    messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser("user","/topic/greeting",
            "asdsadasd1212");
}
```

and configuration in both cases:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker

    public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

        @Override
        public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
            config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
            config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/ws");
        }

        @Override
        public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
            registry.addEndpoint("/hello").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
        }

    }
```

I don't understand how to send message properly from other application. I guess I need to retrieve and store sessionId somewhere and then use for replying. Also, should I create config and controller for replying and what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately I have managed to solve this situation. First, I didn't find a way to interact with page directly from other application and I believe that it's not possible, because connection is required. I decided to use a Jersey endpoint on first app that has a websocket connection to the page. So, the second app calls REST url of the first app and then first app sends websocket message.

**IMPORTANT   IMPORTANT!!!!!**

If you have in your app a "/" context that mapped, for example, to spring-mvc, make it /mvc or anything else. Because if you have more than one context in spring (root and servlet contexts), spring websocket messaging infrastructure creates N sets of beans where N is number of your contents. So I faced a situation when WS session was registered in one context, but session check, convertAndSend method, etc, runned in other context. I spent some hours on that. If you see a situation when you can't send a message to subscribed session, please go to

```
org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.DefaultSubscriptionRegistry#getSubscriptions(String destination, Message<?> message).
```

And if you see that

```
subscriptionRegistry.getAllSubscriptions()
```

is empty, please check your "/" context and make it not "/".